# How to pass complex, non serializable object to android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Hello fellow Android developers,

I wanna know how do you guys pass complex non serializable (& non parcelable) object to fragments. (such as Listener, Api client, ...)

Let me explain my use case:

## The use case

I'm building an Android application composed of one "host" activity and 3 fragments. 
Currently I'm passing the object using a custom constructor on the fragment (bad practice I know).

The fragments constructors looks like the following:

```java
/**
 * Do not remove ever or you'll face RuntimeException
 */
public FirstFragment() {
}

public FirstFragment(Session session,
                     ApiClient apiClient,
                     FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics) {
    mSession = session;
    mApiClient = apiClient;
    mFirebaseAnalytics = firebaseAnalytics;
}
```

And I'm using them in the host activity like this

```java
private FirstFragment getFirstFragment() {
    if (mFirstFragment == null) {
        mFirstFragment = new FirstFragment(mSession, mApiClient, mFirebaseAnalytics);
    }
    return mHomeFragment;
}

[...]

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.commit();
}

[...]

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case FIRST_FRAGMENT_RES_ID:
                    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.first_fragment_title);
                    loadFragment(getFirstFragment(), "first_fragment");
                    return true;
                [...]
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

This solution works well almost all the time. But sometimes (and I don't know when exactly) the default constructor is invoked and therefore all local members are null.

## Possible solutions

To solve the problem I'm thinking about the following solutions:

### Singletons, singletons everywhere

Most of the objects I'm passing are singletons therefore I can access them in the default constructor of the fragments:

```java
public FirstFragment() {
    mSession = Session.getInstance(getContext());
    mApiClient = ApiClient.getInstance(getContext());
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext());
}
```

#### Problems

However the above solution wouldn't work if I need to pass a callback or something. How can it be done like this then?

### Access the objects using parent activity

I think it's one of the ugliest possible solutions because it will couple the Fragments to the parent activity. The idea is something like this

```java
public FirstFragment() {
    mSession = Session.getInstance(getContext());
    mApiClient = ApiClient.getInstance(getContext());
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext());
    mListener = (Listener) getActivity(); // <- will works because parent activity implement the interface
}
```

### Using broadcast & receiver

The idea is to keep passing singleton everywhere and use broadcast & receiver instead of listener.

How do you guys managed this scenario?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do not pass it in constructor, instead create getter and setter in fragment to pass and get the objects.

Comment: @ShivamYadav like I have said in the question, the fragment default constructor is being invoked I don't know when therefore I don't know when to invoke the setters

Comment: The constructor will be invoked when you will instantiate your fragment, a good practice is to instantiate your fragment in a static method and returning the instance from that method. Than with the help of that instance you can call your setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been several months and I have now come up with a different solution.

## For the UI related data

For the UI related stuff I'm now using the [androidx livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

## For the complex non serializable data

My use case was to pass complex object to the fragment, such as manager, parent activity (trough a listener), etc... The approach I have taken is by injecting these data manually from the parent activity.

The first things to do was to remove the objects from the fragment constructor and use the default constructor instead, so that I won't face any instantiation errors.

Then I have created an **inject()** method on the fragment classes that look like this:

```
public void inject(BillingManager billingManager, Listener listener) {
    mBillingManager = billingManager;
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Each fragment will have their own inject method width the objects that should be injected as parameters.

In the parent activity I have override the **onAttachFragment()** method to handle the fragment attach process:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    if (fragment.getClass().equals(FirstFragment.class)) {
        ((FirstFragment) fragment).inject(mBillingManager, this);
    } else if (fragment.getClass().equals(HomeFragment.class)) {
        ((HomeFragment) fragment).inject(this);
    }
}
```

Simple, and now everything work great.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into dependency injection (using a tool like Dagger or alternatives), especially for objects like an Api Client. Post the setup, you'd define, just once, how an Api Client instance could be constructed. And later you can use it pretty much everywhere with a one-line statement. The instance is guaranteed to be available upon the fragment instantiation. Further reading: https://dagger.dev/tutorial/

Comment: I know about Dagger but isn't too much for my use case ? I'll take a look anyway.

Comment: I don't have enough context to judge :) But if this is production code that's expected to live for longer than weeks, then DI (not necessarily with Dagger) is definitely beneficial. You will want to write tests, and without DI it's quite a challenge.

Comment: Also wouldn't think having an API client present in the view layer (Activity/Fragment) is exactly clean. But that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 1):

According to your use case, it might be easier to use a `ViewModel` and store your objects there. Your ViewModel will be shared across your fragments and your host 
activity.
See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: I don't think using ViewModel correspond to my use case. I need to passe non serializable data such as listener and api client.

Comment: @americium1997 You have one activity that contains the fragments correct?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using "Shared" ViewModel?

Essentially, a sub-class of `ViewModel` (which is class designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way for activities and fragments) can be created like below,

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel()
```

Inside this class you can have your custom objects with their correct state

Next, in your 1st Fragment you can obtain a handle to this SharedViewmodel like below,

```
class MasterFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel
```

And obtain the handle to it using below code,

```
model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
}
```

You can write your own logic/method/flow inside `SharedViewModel` to manipulate any custom object's states.

And once all this is done, In your 2nd Fragment, you can create the handle to `SharedViewModel` similar to above code and using `SharedViewModel` object you can retrieve the "modified" custom object from same `SharedViewModel`

Comment: Isn't view model design to contains only serializable UI related fields ?

Comment: what you said is correct as per the android official docs for the "typical" use case of view model classes. however in my view the biggest take away with viewmodel is that they survive the lifecycle events and are accessible at activity/fragment context and sharing data between them

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look !

Comment: sure - in the early years of android all code for data for UI was fetched in activity/fragment class code itself thus making them huge god objects. No one recommended such use - however developers had no other "clean" way in those days to manage data for activity/fragment. Hence in last 2/3 years Google came up with this Jetpack libraries (which includes viewmodel) to address Architecture issues such as what you are facing